# Can anyone guide on generating UUID and then sending confirm link in Spring MVC

Tags: java, email, spring-mvc

I have function in controller like

```
Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();

      session.save(person);
```

Now i want to generate UUID and send the link in email

```
http://www.abc.com/confirm?uusi=1234
```

Can anyone give me some code of how actually generating UUID and what to do fater click

If anyone can give me some online link showing this example. This is the common one should on internet

Answer (score 2):

Knowing this is an old thread, it's still being returned relevant by google. There are 3 UUID generators in Spring itself - all three sharing one interface: `org.springframework.util.IdGenerator` (introduced in Spring 4.0). Implementations are:

- [SimpleIdGenerator](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/util/SimpleIdGenerator.html) since 4.1.5
- [JdkIdGenerator](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/util/JdkIdGenerator.html) since 4.1.5
- [AlternativeJdkIdGenerator](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/util/AlternativeJdkIdGenerator.html) since 4.0

Answer (score 1):

You can generate UUID and for maximum uniqueness add current time milliseconds. Then, hash it with any algorithm.

```
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.util.UUID;

public class UUIDTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
        long currentTimeMillis = System.currentTimeMillis();
        UUID randomUUID = UUID.randomUUID();

        String uuid = randomUUID.toString() + "-" + currentTimeMillis ;
        MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
        md.update(uuid.getBytes());
        byte[] mb = md.digest();
        String out = "";

        for (int i = 0; i < mb.length; i++) {
            byte temp = mb[i];
            String s = Integer.toHexString(new Byte(temp));
            while (s.length() < 2) {
                s = "0" + s;
            }
            s = s.substring(s.length() - 2);
            out += s;
        }

        System.out.println(out);
    }

}
```

Comment: this is pointless. it gives an illusion of something extra, but really does nothing.

Comment: The whole point of a UUID is its uniqueness property. You have to take a look at the maths before trying to "improve" their generation.

Answer (score 0):

java.util.UUID.randomUUID()

then just send that in an email. - or did you need something more complex?

Comment: can you provide some code about what to do after user click on link

Comment: well - i don't know what you want to do, but it would be something like: click-> causes some "action to run" -> in action generate id -> generate email message from id and some other info -> send email message to user with content -> return some html to browser saying "i sent you a mail hooray"